# How to simulate Rust's Mutex<Object> in C++?

Tags: c++, rust

Having an object and a mutex as 2 different variables is kinda error prone

```cpp
MyObject myObject;
std::mutex myObjectMutex;
```

I tend to forget to lock it sometimes.

On Rust, a shared object is required to be inside a mutex:

```rust
std::sync::Mutex<MyObject> mySharedObject
```

So I have to use like this:

```rust
mySharedObject.lock().unwrap().objectMethod()
```

What would be the less error prone way to simulate something like this in C++ so I don't forget to lock it?

I thought of an `std::tuple<std::mutex, MyObject>` but it's not very good and I can forget to lock.

Comment: https://youtu.be/ozOgzlxIsdg

Comment: `mySharedObject.lock().unwrap().objectMethod()` is effectively `myObjectMutex.lock(); myObject.objectMethod(); myObjectMutex.unlock();` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Effectively, yes. The `lock` method returns a smart pointer to the value behind the mutex, and the pointer's destructor releases the mutex lock automatically.

Comment: you can mimick the same in C++ with a `std::unique_ptr` with custom deleter

Comment: This looks similar to an idea I had described here: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/issues/924 with a preliminary implementation here:  https://github.com/galik/GSL/blob/lockable-objects/include/gsl/gsl_lockable

Comment: i though I had an idea for an answer, but I was wrong. Now I wonder how Rust prevents the user from storing the result of `mySharedObject.lock().unwrap()`, let the smart pointers destructor unlock the mutex and then use the stored reference without having a lock

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Taking a reference to the mutex guard creates what Rust considers a *borrow*, and you can't hold a borrow to the guard while the guard itself goes out of scope. Rust's [tag:borrow-checker] checks things like this, which is how Rust can prevent use-after-free errors and data races at compile time.

Answer (score 7):

One way to do it is have your `Mutex<T>` only allow access to the contained `T` via a lambda:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Mutex {
private:
    T value;
    std::mutex mutex;

public:
    // Fill out some constructors, probably some kind of emplacement constructor too.
    // For simplicity of the example, this should be okay:
    explicit Mutex(T value)
        : value(std::move(value))
    {}

    template <typename F>
    auto locked(F&& fn) const& -> std::invoke_result_t<F&&, T const&> {
        // Lock the mutex while invoking the function.
        // scoped_lock automatically unlocks at the end of the scope
        std::scoped_lock lock(mutex);
        return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(fn), value);
    }

    template <typename F>
    auto locked(F&& fn) & -> std::invoke_result_t<F&&, T&> {
        std::scoped_lock lock(mutex);
        return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(fn), value);
    }

    // Can be worth repeating for const&& and && as well
};
```

Usage:

```cpp
mySharedObject.locked([] (MyObject& obj) { return obj.objectMethod(); });
```

It's still possible to defeat this by stashing a reference to the `obj` inside a `.locked(...)` call and using the reference outside of `.locked(...)`, but that would almost require deliberately trying to do the wrong thing.

Also, be aware that it being in a lambda can be quite limiting, as regular control flow no longer works (`return` doesn't return from the outer scope, `continue`/`break` don't work, etc.)

Comment: I only realized how easy it was to get a reference to the `obj` with my approach after writing a (now deleted) answer, hence I was curious. It is possible but one definitely has to do the wrong thing on purpose to get a reference out of your `Mutex` https://godbolt.org/z/GW91qP9Mv

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It's a lot easier to leak the reference than that: https://godbolt.org/z/r5c6vKK54

Comment: Should I use `Mutex<shared_ptr<MyObject>>` or `shared_ptr<Mutex<MyObject>>`?

Comment: why I cannot use `[](auto& lockedObject){}`?

Comment: @Rafaelo Those two types have different meanings, so it depends. If you have multiple threads that need to access a shared_ptr, then do the former. But if your multiple threads only need to know about the `MyObject`, then do the latter, as you can share just a reference to the `Mutex<MyObject>`.

Comment: @Rafaelo You absolutely can, I just didn't

Comment: yes thats easier, but its still like "hey, lets break this api" rather than an innocent "lets store a reference to a returned value, what can be wrong about that?"

Answer (score 1):

I think the following is very near regardless of the lifetime parameter

```cpp
#include <atomic>

template<class T>
class MutexGuard{
    T& inner;
    std::atomic_flag & locked;
public:
    MutexGuard(T& inner, std::atomic_flag& locked): inner{inner}, locked{locked}{}
    operator T&()&{
        return inner;
    }
    ~MutexGuard(){
        locked.clear();
    }
};
template<class T>
class Mutex{
    std::atomic_flag locked{false};
    T inner;
public:
    Mutex(T&& inner):inner{std::move(inner)}{}
    Mutex(const T&) = delete;
    MutexGuard<T> lock(){
        while(locked.test_and_set());
        return MutexGuard<T>{inner, locked};
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e8714c8de7f4454)

Comment: note that this easily breaks when the caller does `auto& x = myMutex.lock().operator T&();`. It offers convenience but no safety

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It's safe from the data races view but not from the dangling references view.

Comment: `x` is not dangling, but its a reference that can be used without holding a lock

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes u r right.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number take a look now.

Comment: nice idea but no big difference: https://godbolt.org/z/vzoc1Trx9. Don't get me wrong, I am not saying that this is a bad answer. I am just saying that it should be noted that it isnt particularly difficult to use it wrong (and I don't think there is an easy fix).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number u r right again. I think to achieve that we must enforce some behaviors statically like rust.

Comment: I think this answer is great, and `.operator T&()` should be considered incorrect usage of this class. Just like `std::unique_ptr`, you are not supposed to de-reference it like `void *ptr2 = & (*ptr)` and use it after the `ptr` itself is destructed. That is the user's fault and should lead to undefined behavior. Upvoted!